# Laravel public/subfolder another source code

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

anybody know how to let laravel some route to another folder inside laravel public folder, current folder structure:

```
public
   index.php <==== this is laravel index.php
   .htaccess <==== this is laravel default .htaccess
   subfolder <==== this is not laravel php code files
```

in my localhost, i can visit the subfolder with url http://example.dev/subfolder

but in my live site, http://example.com/subfolder throw me error of

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

here is the laravel .htaccess files

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

both local/live server source code are sync, i guess this is some server settings issues but i dont know what is the keyword, appreciate for all the help

btw, laravel 5.2 version

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, rather than routing to a folder, you make routes to a particular page.

If you have a structure like

```
public
  index.php <==== this is laravel index.php
  .htaccess <==== this is laravel default .htaccess
  subfolder <==== this is not laravel php code files
     test.blade.php <==== this is a simple webpage
```

and you want to route it to `test.blade.php`, you're route should be something like this

In your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return View::make('subfolder.test');
});
```

So when you will open http://example.dev/test, it will show you the contents of the page `test.blade.php` which is inside the `subfolder`

Comment: there is some other code done by other programmer which in pure php, so must do this

Answer (score 0):

check httpd.conf settings. look for this file

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

compare settings in your local and live site

Comment: both local/live are pointing to /path/to/source/public, any problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem

the live server using WHM/CPANEL, need to add

```
AllowOverride All
```

to the httpd.conf